# Jquery .on versus .live

Tags: jquery

I know that **`.live()` is now deprecated** but I cannot seem to change it and keep the functionality.

I just have a quick question about the `.on()` function in jQuery. I'm currently using `.live()` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/unwsr/18/)

Like so:

```
$('table tr th').live("click", function() {
});
```

But, when I try and replace `.live()` with `.on()` it no longer works as it's supposed to.

I've tried putting in

```
$('table tr th').on("click", function() {
});
```

as well as

```
$('table tr').live("click", "th", function() {
});
```

and

```
$('table tr').delegate("th", "click", function() {
});
```

but to no avail.

Why is this and what steps can I take to make it work properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

Comment: @FelixKling I'm trying to avoid using `$(document)` to mimic the call exactly. I was wondering if there was another way to do it that's more in line with the examples on the jQuery API site.

Comment: Simply take the closest existing element (ancestor) (which would more correspond to `.delegate` then).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `on()` function requires a syntactical update, you should alter your code to:

```
$('body').on("click", "table tr th", function()...
```

Check out this article for more info: http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$('table tr th').live("click", function() {
```

should be

```
$(document).on("click", "table tr th", function() {
```

That is how you would mimic the `.live` call exactly. You could of course limit your selector from document to something more meaningful based on your DOM structure.

Edit:

Just to clarify, in your example, you are required to use `$(document).on(...` because the table doesn't have any parents and is replaced during the life of your page.

Comment: So because I'm replacing the table in the code I need to use `$(document)` so that the call continues to work throughout?

Comment: @Andrew: No, any existing element in the hierarchy will do.

Comment: If the event can not be attached to the element itself, it must be attached to a higher element in the hierarchy that always exists. Like document oder body.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the selected element (the th/tr) exists when the page is loaded initially.
The new .on won't work if this selector is added later to the DOM.

Try

```
$('body').on('click', 'thesSelectorForYourTriggerElement', function(){
    //callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow guess that you are adding `tr` elements into your table, not `th`.

```
$('table').on("click", "tr th", function(){});
```

Comment: The `<th>`s are generated from an array and written into the first `<tr>` of the table. Your solution does not work though...

Comment: That won't work, his table gets replaced using `.replaceWith()`