# getting jquery .on() to work with dynamic html

Tags: jquery, dhtml

This works just fine in jQuery 1.6.4 for dynamic html:

```
$(".selector").die().live("click", function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

but I noticed in jQuery 1.7.1 that `.live()` is deprecated and replaced by `.on()`. How can I use `.on()` with dynamic html? Using `.die().on("click", function())` doesn't work and neither does `.off().on("click", function())`.

Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to use `on` and `off` yesterday but it just didn't seem to work the way I expected, in the end I just used `bind` and `unbind` to do the job

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method works in much the same way that [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) did in older versions of jQuery. You need to use it on an ancestor element and supply a selector. Since DOM events bubble up from the target, they will eventually reach the ancestor element you have used `on` on. When the event reaches that element, the target is checked to see if it matches your selector. If so, the event handler is executed:

```
$("#someAncestor").on("click", ".selector", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

There has been no need to use `live` since `delegate` was added, some time around version 1.4. Using `delegate` the above snippet would be:

```
$("#someAncestor").delegate(".selector", "click", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

`delegate` and `on` are far more efficient than `live`, since `live` always binds event handlers to the `document`. That means every single event triggered on the page has to be tested to see if it matches the selector and should therefore cause an event handler to run. With `on`, only events that bubble to the ancestor element will require this check.