# jQuery - Converting .live to .on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)
>   [.live() vs .on() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215237/live-vs-on-method)

I have the following code (which I've simplified for this) which worked fine alongside jquery-1.7.

```
$("td.ui-datepicker-week-col a").live("click", function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

I'm trying to upgrade my code though so I can upgrade my jQuery pack version so I've changed it to this.

```
$("td.ui-datepicker-week-col").on("click", "a", function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

This doesn't do anything though. It doesn't throw any errors either so I can't see where the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `td.ui-datepicker-week-col` 'lives' on page load?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have `"td.ui-datepicker-week-col"` element at start, then you must choose an existing permanent set. For example

```
$(document).on("click", "td.ui-datepicker-week-col a", function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

The `on` function, contrary to `live`, will only work with the set as it is defined when you call the binding function. What is dynamic is the interpretation of the selector passed as argument to `on` when an event occurs.

Comment: You got a typo, there's one quote too much before `td.ui-datepicker-week-col`.

Comment: despite the typo (which I'm sure you'll edit), a great answer explained well enough for simpleton me to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your `on` statement binds to elements *that already exist at the time of the call*. To properly use delegation, you need to pick an element that exists at the time, and is guaranteed to be a parent element of the event element. If nothing else, you can always use `document` (this is what `live` did, too!)

```
$(document).on("click", "td.ui-datepicker-week-col a", function(e) { /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click", "td.ui-datepicker-week-col a", function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that `"td.ui-datepicker-week-col"` was not present at the DOM at the time the page was loaded and the `on` event attached.

Attach the handler to an parent element, which will be there at the time of the javascript code load. The simplest (and worse, but working) is:

```
$("body").on("click", "td.ui-datepicker-week-col a", function () {
  alert("hello")
})
```

This will be triggered for every click on document, then jQuery will verify if the clicked element is `"td.ui-datepicker-week-col a"` and, if true, execute the callback.

A more efficient way to do this is to attach to an existing subcontainer in which `"td.ui-datepicker-week-col a"` will be for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('.ui-datepicker-week-col').on('click', 'a', function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

And see this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pUByL/1/)

Greetings.