# Dollar Hash and variable - $('#

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, toggle

So, to show and hide certain DIV tags within my site I got the following codes

```
$('#ONE').live('click', function () {
    $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('#b-ONE').css('display', 'block');
});
$('#TWO').live('click', function () {
    $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('#b-TWO').css('display', 'block');
});
```

where a click on the div namend "ONE" opens a certain "b-ONE" div, and so on. It works flawlessly but is a pain when the list gets longer. You see where it says "ONE" and "TWO" in the JS ... is there any way I can turn these "ONE" and "TWO" into variables, so I can have up to 40 divs and don't have to type the above code for every DIV, and have a sleek code where I only have to type that finction once with variables?

I'm looking into something like this but lack the in-depth JS / jQuery knowledge:

```
$('#VARIABLETEXT').live('click', function () {
    $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('#b-VARIABLETEXT').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Where a click on a div named "TWENTYONE" shows the div "b-TWENTYONE"

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: At some point you should start planning to use the current suggested way(s) of binding jQuery event handlers. The `.live()` API has been deprecated for quite a while now (years).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `id` of the clicked element when building the selector for the element you want to change:

```
$('#ONE, #TWO, #THREE').live('click', function () {
    $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('#b-' + this.id).css('display', 'block');
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

The initial selector (`"#ONE, #TWO, #THREE"`) can probably be better written by giving all of those elements the same class attribute, and then using `.the-class`.

There may also be a structural approach, but as you haven't quoted your HTML, it's impossible to say.

---

Side note: The `live` function is not only deprecated, but actually removed from recent vesrions of jQuery. Here's the up-to-date equivalent:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ONE, #TWO, #THREE', function () {
    $('.hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('#b-' + this.id).css('display', 'block');
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Comment: Also, using `.hide()` and `.show()` it's almost always a good idea

Comment: use .on instead of .live http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215237/live-vs-on-method

Comment: @patel.milanb: !! I didn't even notice the use of `.live`! Thank you, I've added a note about it.

Comment: T.J., Nico,, Patel ... thanks a million!! That did it! Stunning! I just encountered stackoverflow and just signed up ... hopefully I can give something back to the cmmunity here!