# How to port deprecated .live() jQuery code to the current version

Tags: javascript, jquery, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: how to replace .live with .on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604328/jquery-how-to-replace-live-with-on)

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. I just upgraded jQuery to 1.9.0 in our application and I saw that we used tons of `.live()` calls in the past.

I ported all the `.live()` calls to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) calls. In most cases it's a straightforward update (simple cases like the one in the second snippet on the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) page). But at several places I have something like:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ui-jqgrid-btable').find('a.pop_dialog_jqgrid').live('click', function() {
            //some code here
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

which I have ported to:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', $('.ui-jqgrid-btable').find('a.pop_dialog_jqgrid'), function() {
            //some code here
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But it's not doing the same thing at all with the new code (all the clicks anywhere on the page fire the "some code").

Anyone can enlighten me please?

Comment: Check the answer by @Joseph....I would also recommend to add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script> to your pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument should be a selector, not an object:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-jqgrid-btable a.pop_dialog_jqgrid', function() {
     //some code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a selector, not a jQuery object. Personally, I would localize it a bit more than document.

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-btable').on('click', 'a.pop_dialog_jqgrid', function() {
    //some code here
});
```