# jquery migration from 1.7 to 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'am trying to migrate from jquery 1.7 to 1.10 and the live function do not work anymore.

```
$("#detail_content").on("click", ".close", function (a) {  // is ignored
//$("#detail_content .close").live("click", function (a) { //works fine with migrate
  console.log("click");
});
```

the div.detail_content is loading later via ajax but the close button do not work anymore if i change from .live to .on

I think the delegation is missing.

any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to replace .live with .on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604328/jquery-how-to-replace-live-with-on)

Comment: it is not duplicated. the syntax is ok. In this case is the missing static parent the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `#detail_content` also is an dynamic one, then try

```
$(document).on("click", "#detail_content .close", function (a) {  // is ignored
//$("#detail_content .close").live("click", function (a) { //works fine with migrate
  console.log("click");
});
```

Comment: thx thats it. I'am new in jquery. With mootools you do not need a static element.

Answer (score 2):

You should use any closest **static** parent element (or `body` at last):

```
$("body").on("click", "#detail_content .close", function() { ... });
```

So if you have the markup like:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="container">
        ...
        <div id="detail_content"><button class="close">Close</button></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and `#container` is not replaced after Ajax call, then it is better to use:

```
$("#container").on("click", "#detail_content .close", function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.live()` method is deprecated in jQuery 1.10 and above. Use `.on()` method to attach event handlers.

So you can use this code instead of .live()

```
 $(document).on('click', '#detail_content .close', function(){
      //your Code
 });
```

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button/20819663#20819663) is useful for you and in [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) you can see all deprecated method and it's useful for someone who want to migration from 1.7 to 1.10

Answer (score 0):

VisioN, is it not the same to just use the following?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});
```

Is there something about the code above that is slower or less efficient somehow?