# jquery - Click event not working for dynamically created button

Tags: jquery, html

My requirement is to create number of buttons equal to the json array count. I was successful in creating buttons dynamically in jquery. But the method in .ready function of jquery is not called for the click action. I have tried searching in SO. Found few solutions but nothing worked for me. I am very new to jquery. Please help...

my code:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    currentQuestionNo = 0;
    var questionsArray;
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/Sample/JsonCreation.php', function(data)
    {   
        questionsArray = data;
        variable = 1;
            //CREATE QUESTION BUTTONS DYNAMICALLY ** NOT WORKING
        for (var question in questionsArray)
        {
            var button = $("<input>").attr("type", "button").attr("id", "questionButton").val(variable);

            $('body').append(button);

                        //Tried using .next here - but it dint work...
            //$('body').append('<button id="questionButton">' + variable + '</button>');
            variable++;
        }
        displayQuestionJS(questionsArray[currentQuestionNo], document);
    });




    $("button").click(function()
    {

        if ($(this).attr('id') == "nextQuestion")
        {
            currentQuestionNo = ++currentQuestionNo;
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('id') == "previousQuestion")
        {
            currentQuestionNo = --currentQuestionNo;
        }

        displayQuestionJS(questionsArray[currentQuestionNo], document);

    });



function displayQuestionJS(currentQuestion, document) 
{
    document.getElementById('questionNumber').innerText  = currentQuestion.questionNumber;
    document.getElementById('questionDescription').innerText  = currentQuestion.quesDesc;
    $('label[for=optionA]').html(currentQuestion.optionA);
    $('label[for=optionB]').html(currentQuestion.optionB);
    $('label[for=optionC]').html(currentQuestion.optionC);
}

HTML content
<form method="post" name="formRadio">

<label id="questionNumber"></label>. &nbsp;
<label id="questionDescription"></label>   <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionA"> </input> <label for="optionA"></label> <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionB"> </input> <label for="optionB"></label> <br />
<input type="radio" id="optionC"> </input> <label for="optionC"></label> <br />

<button id="previousQuestion">Previous Question</button>
<button id="nextQuestion">Next Question</button>

<br />
<br />

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitTest" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

EDIT -- Sample .on Method code - Separate file: WORKING - THANKS A LOT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var button = '<input type="button" id="button2" value="dynamic button">';
        $('body').append(button);
    });
});

$(document).on('click','#button2', function()
{
    alert("Dynamic button action");
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="button">Static Button</button>

</body>
```

Comment: @Barmer Can anyone please let me know why is the below code not working? $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) { alert("asd"); });

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You create buttons dynamically because of that you need to call them with `.live()` method if you use jquery 1.7

but this method is deprecated (you can see the list of all deprecated method [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)) in newer version. if you want to use jquery 1.10 or above you need to call your buttons in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){ 
     // Your Code
});
```

For Example

If your html is something like this

```
<div id="btn-list">
    <div class="btn12">MyButton</div>
</div>
```

You can write your jquery like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-list .btn12', function(){ 
     // Your Code
});
```

Comment: This method is fantastic.  It uses the document object and finds whatever buttons are there, whether old or new (dynamically created).

Comment: @majid, even $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){ 
      alert("asd");
 }); is not working.... On tap of a dynamically created button, alert is not popping up... Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: @vivin, i add an Example to my Answer

Comment: @majid... Done Sir. One more clarification. Inside my getjson function, I have questionsArray. When i try to access question.questionNumber, i get a "undefined" message. My json looks like [{"questionNumber":"1","quesDesc":"The price...?","optionA":"25%",...,"selectedAnswer":null},{"questionNumber":"2","que‌​sDesc":"Price ...?","optionA":"9.09%",...,"selectedAnswer":null},...]. No issues in the Format. Please let me know how to access the values in the json data using the same for loop...

Comment: i can't answer your question in comment clearly but this link answer your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: I didn't know about this new technique
$(document).on('click', '#ID', function(){  }
I was trying with the old $("button").click(function(){} technique and wasted my most of the day. Thanks alot man!

Comment: Its working , is ther any way to bind the button to an event ynamically , to call a function

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that the buttons you created are not yet on the page by the time you bind the button. Either bind each button in the `$.getJSON` function, or use a dynamic binding method like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    ...
});
```

Note you probably don't want to do this on the 'body' tag, but instead wrap the buttons in another div or something and call `on` on it.

[jQuery On Method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

the simple and easy way to do that is use on event:

```
$('body').on('click','#element',function(){
    //somthing
});
```

but we can say this is not the best way to do this. I suggest a another way to do this is use clone() method instead of using dynamic html.
Write some html in you file for example:

```
<div id='div1'></div>
```

Now in the script tag make  a clone of this div then all the properties of this div would follow with new element too. For Example:

```
var dynamicDiv = jQuery('#div1').clone(true);
```

Now use the element dynamicDiv wherever you want to add it or change its properties as you like. Now all jQuery functions will work with this element

Answer (score -1):

You could also create the input button in this way:

```
var button = '<input type="button" id="questionButton" value='+variable+'> <br />';
```

It might be the syntax of the Button creation that is off somehow.

Comment: Both have the same action right? Or do we have some specifics in the suggested way?