# Jquery confirm dialog appears at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

first of all sorry if i am asking a silly question, as i dont have much experience in using JQuery.

My prolem is that i am using a Jquery alert with YES NO button (rather than using the default CONFIRM dailog of JSP which have the OK and Cancel button). Now when i use the JQuery, application is displaying the correct message to the user with Yes No buttons but the alert box is not poping out on the screen, instead it display at the bottom of the page.

Whats wrong ... i am unable to find any clue.... Any idea?

```
jQuery.alerts.okButton = ' Yes ';
jQuery.alerts.cancelButton = ' No ';


jConfirm('Do you want to change the default case?', 'Confirm', function(r) {
    if (r == false)
    {
        alert('No Clicked');

    }
    else
    {
        alert('Yes Clicked');
    }

});
```

where as the JConfirm() method is defined in the related .JS file as follows

```
jConfirm = function(message, title, callback) {
    $.alerts.confirm(message, title, callback);
};
```

Where as the related confirm method is:

```
    confirm: function(message, title, callback) {
        if( title == null ) title = 'Confirm';
        $.alerts._show(title, message, null, 'confirm', function(result) {
            if( callback ) callback(result);
        });
    },
```

and the _show method is:

```
    _show: function(title, msg, value, type, callback) {

        $.alerts._hide();
        $.alerts._overlay('show');

        $("BODY").append(
          '<div id="popup_container">' +
            '<h1 id="popup_title"></h1>' +
            '<div id="popup_content">' +
              '<div id="popup_message"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>');

        if( $.alerts.dialogClass ) $("#popup_container").addClass($.alerts.dialogClass);

        // IE6 Fix
        var pos = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed'; 

        $("#popup_container").css({
            position: pos,
            zIndex: 99999,
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0
        });

        $("#popup_title").text(title);
        $("#popup_content").addClass(type);
        $("#popup_message").text(msg);
        $("#popup_message").html( $("#popup_message").text().replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );

        $("#popup_container").css({
            minWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth(),
            maxWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth()
        });

        $.alerts._reposition();
        $.alerts._maintainPosition(true);

        switch( type ) {
            case 'alert':
                $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /></div>');
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    callback(true);
                });
                $("#popup_ok").focus().keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                });
            break;
            case 'confirm':
                $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    if( callback ) callback(true);
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    if( callback ) callback(false);
                });
                $("#popup_ok").focus();
                $("#popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                    if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                });
            break;
            case 'prompt':
                $("#popup_message").append('<br /><input type="text" size="30" id="popup_prompt" />').after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                $("#popup_prompt").width( $("#popup_message").width() );
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    var val = $("#popup_prompt").val();
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    if( callback ) callback( val );
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    if( callback ) callback( null );
                });
                $("#popup_prompt, #popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                    if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                });
                if( value ) $("#popup_prompt").val(value);
                $("#popup_prompt").focus().select();
            break;
            case 'confirmyesno':
                $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.yesButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.noButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    //alert("press yes button");
                        $.alerts._hide();
                        if( callback ) callback(true);
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                    //alert("press no button");
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    if( callback ) callback(false);
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").focus();
            break;

        }
```

Comment: Check out the [Documentation for position on the jQuery UI site](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

Comment: post the code or fiddle

Comment: please append your code. if you load your code dynamically maybe this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button/20819663#20819663

Comment: Problem not describe as it should. Please post the code

Comment: i have posted  the code.....

Comment: @bilal , please create jsfiddle to get answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because of styling. CSS code below should force `#popup_container` to be displayed in one, predefined place [(0,0) is the default position].

```
#popup_container{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Silveraven, thx for your time but i am unable to understand the change u r suggesting. Can u please type the exact code change from my above posted code...

Comment: All the code you added is jQuery. Styling for page you should do in CSS (`<style></style>` in `<head>` section for example). That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @ Silveraven: Thx for your time. My problem is resolved now but slightly different way. I have to change the 'position' to 'absolute' rather than fixed and it works for me.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to get :) Good to know that you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using npm: Make sure you imported CSS into your page

e.g.

```
@import "~jquery-confirm/dist/jquery-confirm.min.css";
```