# javascript checkbox - uncheck only on bootstrap modal OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I need to add some javascript to.

I am having issues getting this to work because I have a bootstrap modal that has Cancel and Confirm buttons.

I am unsure how to pass the un-check reference to the modal code and uncheck the checkbox on on the Confirm button. I have made many attempts but failed on all attempts.

**How do I do un-ceck the checkbox only when the user selects the Confirm button on the bootstrap modal.** When the user selects the modal Cancel button, the checkbox should stay checked.

Here is the checkbox code that I currently have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected_items" value="{{ id }}" {% if selected %}checked="checked"{% endif %} data-confirm="Are you sure you want to uncheck this?" />
```

Here is the bootstrap modal code that I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {

                $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal modal-confirm-max-width" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><icon class="icon-remove"></icon></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="dataConfirmLabel">{% trans "Confirm" %} - {{ resume_detail_temp_value }}</h4></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">{% trans "Cancel" %}</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn-u btn-u-blue" id="dataConfirmOK">{% trans "Confirm" %}</a></div></div>');

            }

            $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').html($(this).attr('data-confirm'));

            $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});

            $('#dataConfirmOK').click(function() {

                // handle checkbox function here.

            });

            return false;

        });

    });
```

Comment: I'm guessing your click handler for `dataConfirmOK` is not even firing since you're creating that element dynamically. You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('#dataConfirmOK').click(function() {
    $('input[name=selected_items]').prop('checked', false);
});
```