# DOM manipulation of Elements added by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding HTML to the DOM with jQuery to an existing empty table with class `sec_sch` like this:

```js
details += "<tr>"+
    "<td class=\"use\">" + this.name + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + this.start_year + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + this.end_year + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + this.qualification + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<button class=\"rmv\">-</button>" + "</td>" +
"</tr>";
$(".sec_sch tbody").append(details);
```

It loads fine but I cannot seem to manipulate the `button.rmv` from the same JS file with such code.

```js
$('.rmv').click(function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
}); // end of remove secondary school
```

please any idea why?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button

Comment: Thanks @Rory, that indeed solved my problems..