# Onclick event handler seems not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON:

```
[{
"i_id":"1",
"i_name":"Biryani",
"i_category":"Pakistani",
"i_Uploader_Name":"Nabeel",
"i_dateofadd":"2016-01-24",
"i_rate":"0",
"image_name":"Biryani-main1.jpg",
"image_path":"images\/Biryani-main1.jpg",
"image_thumb":"thumb\/Biryani-main1.jpg"
}]
```

I want to give to every recipe its different id, so that I can show them anywhere:

```
 $('#btnsearchres').click(function(){
            $("#recipes").empty();
            var content;
            var ingredient=$('#txtsearch').val();
            //$server = 'http://localhost/XDK';     
 $.getJSON(server+"/search.php",{ingredient:ingredient},function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i,data){
    content='<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a">';
    content += '<li><a>' + data.i_category + '</a></li>';
    content += '<li><a href="#"><img src="http://localhost/xdk/'+data.image_thumb+'" style="width:200px;height:200px;"/>';
        content+='<h3>'+data.i_name+'</h3>';
    content += '<p overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">' + data.i_recipe + '</p></a></li>';
        content+='<li><input id="btn'+data.i_id+'" onclick="ViewItem('+data.i_id+','+UserId+')" type="button" value="View" style="padding-top:10px;"/></li>';
        content+='</ul><hr>';
    $(content).appendTo("#recipes");
    });
});
});
```

It is my ViewItemFunction. But when I press on view, it does nothing:

```
 function ViewItem(ItemId,UserId){
    alert("working");//not working
    var content;
    $.ajax({

                           type: "post",
                           dataType  : 'html',
                           url: $server+"/view.php",
                           data: {ItemId:ItemId,UserId:UserId},
                           success: function(result) {
                               alert(result);
                               
                                $(content).appendTo("#");
                            }
                       });
}
```

Comment: What's `UserId`? `[...] onclick="ViewItem('+data.i_id+','+` **UserId** `+')" type="button" [...]` I feel obligated to tell you that [using onClick is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Comment: UserId is 1 in this case

Comment: what can i use other than Onclick?

Comment: As far as I know there are two different alternatives: `$(document).on('click', '#foo', function() { /* do stuff */ })` and `$('#foo').click(function() { /* do stuff */ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this anywhere in your `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    ViewItem($(this).attr('id').substr($(this).attr('id').indexOf('-') + 1), UserId);
}
```

Change this:

```
content+='<li><input id="btn'+data.i_id+'" onclick="ViewItem('+data.i_id+','+UserId+')"
```

To this:

```
content+='<li><input id="btn-'+data.i_id+'"
```

Note the "-" after "btn" and the absence of the "onclick"-part.

I think the problem exists because you add the input dynamically, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button). If this does not help it might be a syntax error, your code is terribly structured and to say the truth I am too lazy to go through it all.

If you use Google Chrome you can press F12 and Click on "Console" to see if there is an error.