# Onclick Event Javascript & JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippets in my main.js file

```
function one(){
  //some code
  var btn = "<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='form_new_receipt()'>Submit</button>";

  document.querySelector('#showGrower').innerHTML += btn;
}
```

The function the submit button is calling is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Do your event binding in JavaScript, not as inline HTML event attributes:
  $("#processReceipt").on("click", form_new_receipt);
  function form_new_receipt() {
    alert('before function');
  }
});
```

What could I be missing because the alert does not show up - meaning the function is not being called.

I had tried this below but it didn't work - that's why I added the $(document).ready

```
function form_new_receipt() {
  alert('before function');
}
```

Comment: any error you are grtting in browser console when clicking button?

Comment: *"What could I be missing?"* Hard to say, you didn't even tell us what is your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - Click event not working for dynamically created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819501/jquery-click-event-not-working-for-dynamically-created-button)

Comment: I couldn't get it, what is the question?

Comment: Move function outside of  `$(document).ready(function() {..});` and check

Comment: "What could i be missing?"
Ans- your question

Comment: @AlivetoDie these are different functions doing different things. I cut out some code to make the question easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
function one(){
var btn = "<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='form_new_receipt()'>Submit</button>";
$('#showGrower').append(btn);
}

$(document).on('click', '#processReceipt', function() {
     one()
});

function form_new_receipt(a) {
    alert('before function');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showGrower"></div>
<button id="processReceipt" type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It has worked but its calling the function 3 times. Its a better prob. Will figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: It has worked but its calling the function 3 times. Its a better prob. Will figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: My example is working, anyway I dont know how is exactly the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the click handler in javascript, you need to set the click handler after adding the button to DOM.

You can add the click handler inside the `one()` function. (I have removed the onclick attribute from the button).

```
function one(){
//some code
var btn = "<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>";

document.querySelector('#showGrower').innerHTML += btn;

    $("#processReceipt").on("click", form_new_receipt);
    function form_new_receipt() {
        alert('before function');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, what you can do is you can attach the click handler to a parent static element like `body`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do your event binding in JavaScript, not as inline HTML event attributes:
    $('body').on("click", "#processReceipt", form_new_receipt);
    function form_new_receipt() {
        alert('before function');
    }

});
```

And of course you don't want to forget to call `one()` function.

Link to jsfiddle for both cases:

https://jsfiddle.net/jej453se/

https://jsfiddle.net/jej453se/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to call one(), Please see below code

```
<div id="showGrower"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function one(){
    var btn = "<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='form_new_receipt()'>Submit</button>";
    document.querySelector('#showGrower').innerHTML += btn;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    one();  // Call one() function 
    $("#processReceipt").on("click", form_new_receipt);
    function form_new_receipt() {
        alert('before function');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for vanillaJS since you're using the jQuery you could also it will be better to prevent the use of `inline-event`'s as `onclick` and attach your click event just from the jQuery code like the following snippet shows.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   one();
});

function one(){
  $('#showGrower').append("<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>");
  
  $("#processReceipt").on("click", form_new_receipt);
}

function form_new_receipt() {
  alert('before function');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="showGrower"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem? what the expected behavior? what the current non-expected behavior? btw you don't need to put `onclick=""` in the html if you add it later on with jQuery. anyway, your code has two conceptual problems:

if you want to use jQuery, you have to bind it once the element is created:

```
function one(){
    //some code
    var btn = "<button type='submit' id='processReceipt' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>";

    document.querySelector('#showGrower').innerHTML += btn;

    $("#processReceipt").on("click", function form_new_receipt() {
        alert('before function');
    }
}
```

if you want to use `onclick` inside html you have to declare the function in the global scope

```
function form_new_receipt() {
    alert('before function');
}
```

you could also create the element with

```
var a = document.createElement('button');
```

and assign properties programmatically

```
a.type = 'submit';
...
```

that is significantly faster and allows you to bind events like

```
a.addEventListener('click', (eventArg) => {
    alert('hello!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: why do you wan to create 2 kinds of code (plain javascript and jquery). You can achieve what you desire with only 1 type.

But still, taking your code, I have created a `codepen`.
Please try, it works:

```
https://codepen.io/vishalkaului/pen/ZapXpG
```

The issue why it wasn't working was you were not executing the `function one`. I have changed it to an `IIFE` which would run automatically without being called explicitly.