# .on() not working on ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My soft.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style>
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("button").on("click",function(){alert("f");});
$("div").on("click",function(){
$("span").load("check.php");
});

});</script></head><body>
<div>Click</div>
<button>eaf</button><span></span>
</body></html>
```

And check.php code

```
<body>
<button>Hello</button>
</body>
```

I want to alert f on clicking on button which is loaded via ajax which was working fine with .live().
But someone told me that .on() can be used in place of live but .on() is not working here.Suggest Solution

Comment: `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7 or above. Which version are you using?

Comment: the one which is stated by you

Comment: You did not properly convert your `.live` code to `.on`. **[Please read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** and/or **[use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on/8021462#)**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('body').on("click", "button", function(){
    alert("f");
});
```

As your `button` added to DOM after page load you need to use delegate event.

It would be better to use something other selector instead of `body`.

You can use multiple selector like follwoing:

```
$('body').on("click", "button, div", function(){
    alert("f");
});
```

Read about [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: can i use on multiple times with body

Comment: what if function for div and button are different

Comment: @Somebody: The same rules that are valid for any event handler registration methods apply to `.on` as well.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble then you should go for different binding

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble no, no. Don't use live event