# JQuery 'on' vs. 'live'

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario where JQuery 'on' & 'live' do not perform the same.  Perhaps someone can point out why.  I am using JQuery 1.7.2 with my project and in this build, 'live' has been replaced with 'on'.  I am using the following code in a listing page.  Basically, this page has an alphabetical bar that the user can click & will load all the clients with that last name.  I would like the link to execute via ajax.

Code:

```
$("a.listajax").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("div.content").load(url + " div.content");
    return false;
});
```

The problem here is that when I first load the page and click on a link, everything works fine.  The page gets loaded via ajax.  However, after that all the links lose their bindings & then if I click on any links, I get an entire page loads.

I replaced the 'on' with 'live' and the links started behaving perfectly, even on subsequent clicks.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One does not simply replace `.live` with `.on`.

```
$("a.listajax").live('click', function(e))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.listajax', function(e))
```

**Important**

If there's a common ancestor for all your `.listajax` anchors that will not be removed from the DOM, you should use that (the deepest one possible) instead of `document`; this will improve performance.

Comment: You should avoid binding to document object.. instead should bind it to a closest container that would be available in dom.

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of `live()`. It rebinds new DOM elements when they are created. There are a lot of similar questions on jQuery's site, like [this one](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-vs-live-click), because it can be a bit confusing.

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/), you use `live()` to:

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

The "...in the future" part is key, because `on()` [does not have that](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: You are right.  This is a bit confusing.  So 'live' will rebind all events.  Isn't 'on' supposed to do the same too?

Comment: It doesn't look like it when I look at jQuery docs, and the question that Vega posted doesn't provide a clean alternative to `live()` in my opinion. Since `live()` still works, I think it's safe to use for now; just watch out in future versions.

Comment: I guess Jack's answer doesn't look too bad, assuming it works. Have you tried it?

Comment: @woz - I agree. It works so its safe to use for this release.  However, Jack's solution also works.