# .on() jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - convert .live() to .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636932/jquery-convert-live-to-on)
>   [JQuery ‘on’ vs. ‘live’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007741/jquery-on-vs-live)
>   [Turning live() into on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

I know .live() is deprecated, but .on() is getting me some errors.
It does not work when I dynamically generate the dome, it only works at the first click. Whilst the same code with .live() works correctly. I'm using jquery 1.8

Working code

```
$('.item').live('click', function(e) {
   alert('test');
   // ajax call that regenerates .item element
});
```

This code only works at the first click:

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
   alert('test');
   // ajax call that regenerates .item element
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You aren't supplying a context. the context for .live is `document`. This has been asked so many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `.on` works slightly different:

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function(event){
    alert('test');
    // ajax call that regenerates .item element
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the dom change with your Ajax you need to provide a parent on your on call like this:

```
$("#itemParent").on("click", ".item", function(event){
  alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As Kevin B mentioned, use document as context of delegation, or better static parent:

```
$(document).on('click','.item', function(e) {
   alert('test');
   // ajax call that regenerates .item element
});
```