# jQuery live() deprecated: Using on for mouseenter and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, events, deprecated, jquery

I wonder how I can rewrite the following listener with jQuery `on()`

```
$('.box').live({
        mouseenter:
        function() {
            $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeIn);
        },
        mouseleave:
        function() {
            $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeOut);
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on and the documentation http://api.jquery.com/live/, http://api.jquery.com/on/. You will find the information about how to convert `.live` to `.on` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('hover', '.box', function(e) {
  if( e.type == 'mouseenter') {
    $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeIn);
  } else {
    $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeOut);
  }
});
```

Instead of `document` it would be better to use any parent element of `.box` which is not dynamic.

Read about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**.

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event (aka live event) is:

```
$( StaticParent ).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction );
```

Answer (score 2):

For **exact** `.on` equivalent:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeIn);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).children('.menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeOut);
    }
}, '.box');
```

Though the main benefit here is that you don't need to use `document`, you can just use the closest parent that is guaranteed to exist for the lifetime of the page.