# JS: get the closest id number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having the following structure:

```
<td class="padding_right padding_left">Neighborhood</td>
<td>
    <div id="neighborhoods_region">    
    <select class="inputs_form_data" id="neighborhood_id2" name="neighborhood_id2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    </div>
</td>
<td width="10%"><a class='delete-region'>remover</a></td>​
```

I'm trying to when the `remove` link is clicked, to get the id number of the select id. In this case, I need to get the number 2 from the "neighborhood_id2".

But first I just trying to get the full id. `neighborhood_id2` with the following code:

```
$(document.body).on('click','a.delete-region', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('select').attr("id"));
});
```

but this returns me `undefined`.

note: the `id` number is generated on-the-fly on a dynamic form. So I may have `neighborhood_id3` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `.closest('tr')` which will get you the `tr` and then find the `select`,

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('select').attr("id"));
```

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502211/js-get-the-closest-id-number/12502228#comment16825242_12502228) pointed out.. use `.on` (delegated events) / `.delegate`

Comment: Better use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated

Comment: @KleberS. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on

Comment: @KleberS. If this works for you.. Please mark is as answered for closure.