# Using a javascript variable in escape_javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, escaping, string-interpolation

I've been trying to get the following to work: I want a jQuery function to load a specific partial when there's being clicked on a certain div with an ID. I want this ID to be part of the :locals which i'm using together with the partial.

```
$("#main>.dots").live("mousedown", function(e) {
        $num = 8;
        $("#main").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'projects/show',     :locals => {:i => "#{$num}"}).html_safe %>")
    })
```

So far I haven't been able to get it right. The code above returns the 'called id for nil' so the $num isnt properly given to the escape_javascript function. When I replace $num with the integer 8 it works (between the <% %> tags).

Any solutions?

the syntax:

```
$("#main").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'projects/show', :locals => {:i => 8}).html_safe %>")
```

works, so thats the way i want to go, except the 8 being jQuery ofcourse

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated (and very slow)

Comment: thx for the reply I'll replace them with 'on()' :) (forgot it was deprecated)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using mousedown instead of click?

Comment: no im changing it to 'click' now but a part of my code doesnt seem to work now. it must all be encased in '$(function() { //code }' right?

Comment: I believe ive found an answer already: jquery can only assign events when classnames already exist, and a lot of my functions are aimed at HTML thats not yet to be loaded on the page. Im reverting back to .live() since that seems to work the best. <-- I'll definitely look for an alternative when i see time

Comment: ok fixed it all with a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on

all fixed up now :) thx for the sidenote

Comment: escape_javascript() is also available through the alias j()

Comment: I knew that but it needs to be understandable for some other people, so short code isnt a requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by doing

```
var dataString = "projectid=" + $(this).attr("id") + "&left=" + $(this).css("left") + '&top=' + $(this).css("top");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/projects/show",
        type: "get",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#main").append(data)
        }
    });
```

So basically I went AJAX so I could send POST-data to the right controller action :)