# jquery.unobtrusive-ajax plugin broken when updating to Jquery 1.9.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on)

//Solution: I simply replaced the four occurrences like the approved answer suggested and unobtrusive ajax plugin is up and working again with jquery 1.9.0

Update//Observe the comments for the answer marked at the bottom which is the best way to solve this.

//Original post:
I upgraded to jQuery 1.9.0 but then unobtrusive ajax plugin went down since they deprecated the live method. I tried to replace it like this since the upgrade fixes an other bug for me. However, it does not work. I simply replaced live with on like this:

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]").on("click", function (evt) {
        var name = evt.target.name,
            $target = $(evt.target),
            form = $target.parents("form")[0],
            offset = $target.offset();

        $(form).data(data_click, [
            { name: name + ".x", value: Math.round(evt.pageX - offset.left) },
            { name: name + ".y", value: Math.round(evt.pageY - offset.top) }
        ]);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(form).removeData(data_click);
        }, 0);
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true] :submit").on("click", function (evt) {
        var name = evt.target.name,
            form = $(evt.target).parents("form")[0];

        $(form).data(data_click, name ? [{ name: name, value: evt.target.value }] : []);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(form).removeData(data_click);
        }, 0);
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true]").on("submit", function (evt) {
        var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (!validate(this)) {
            return;
        }
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method || "GET",
            data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could start by searching stackoverflow or reading the documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @KevinB a bit harsh and unhelpful :/  I hit the same issue and Googled and search Stackoverflow - I hit this question and never came across the one you linked to

Comment: I guess some people just have trouble coming up with good search terms. For example, this one was "convert .live to .on jQuery", the first 6 results i get all show good examples of how to convert `.live` to `.on`.

Comment: I guess I could have formulated my question better but my intention was that others searching for problems with unobtrusive ajax would find this answer. Not everyone with a broken unobtrusive ajax knows its .find that has been deprecated.

Comment: This question is specific to jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax whereas the proposed duplicate is not. The solution here is to get the latest version of jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax (it has been fixed to use `.on()`), not to manually modify it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Equivalent of `live` using `on` (delegation) is:

```
$(document).on("click","a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {...});
```

You can find jquery's `.on()` method documentation here:

[**>>**    http://api.jquery.com/on/    **<<**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see **.bind()**,
>   **.delegate()**, and **.live()**.
>
> **To remove events bound with .on()**, see
>   **.off()**. To attach an event that **runs only once** and then removes
>   itself, see **.one()**

Comment: also check the workarounds here -  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776965/please-support-jquery-v1-9-0-properly-in-jquery-validate-unobtrusive

Comment: and upgrade jquery.validate to 1.11.0 (released today) : https://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation/1.11.0

Comment: There is now an even newer version of jquery.validate : https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation/