# JQuery replacement of live :: `delegate` or `on`

Tags: jquery, jquery-on, jquery-delegate

According to the jQuery API Description: live is completely removed in latest version. But its been used in our projects extensively. For example:

```
$('div.collapsed').live('mouseover', function () {
        TBD.GENERAL.showLoginOther(this);

});

$(".info_bar .filter a, .pagination a").live("click", function () {
    TBD.DHTML.shadeWithLoading($(this).data('container-id'));
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
});

$("form[loading-effect]").live('ajax:before', function () {
    $(this).find('.button_panels, .loading_panels').toggle();
});

.........
```

etc.

Now if I want to use the latest jquery what will be the correct replacement of live? delegate or on ?

Anticipating a bit  explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can find best explanation in documentation i think

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14405273/1414562

Comment: The simplest solution is not to update your version of jQuery unless you have some other, specific reason for doing so.

Comment: I already determined to upgrade :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `.live()` is deprecated you **better** to use `.on()` like

```
$('div.collapsed').on('mouseover', function () {
```

or can use like

```
$(document).on('mouseover','div.collapsed', function () {
```

Because

1. You can’t use .live() for reusable widgets.
2. stopPropagation() doesn't work with live.
3. live() is slower.
4. live() is not chainable.

and the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

Comment: why not `delegate` ? or why `on`. Explanation will be appreciated

Comment: None of them are equivalent to live(). Live attaches event handlers to document level:   `$(document).on('mouseover','div.collapsed', function () {...})`

Comment: both are same as you said i think

Comment: Your edit is better now ;) +1  but you should remove $('div.collapsed').on('mouseover', function () {...}) which bring confusion as it's not delegating event, here, its equivalent to .bind()