# Jquery tooltip ON event not firing after change of datepicker month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events

I've added some basic tooltips to the jquery datepicker plugin but after I change the month the events are no longer bound to their selectors. How can I rebind these events on month change?

A cut down version of what I'm working with is below.

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $("#scene").datepicker();
    var evtd = { 
        March312013: {title: "Ladies Night"}, 
        March302013: {title: "Lilly Allen Tribute Band"}
    }

    $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
        var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month").text();
        var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year").text();
        var day = $(this).text();
        ix = month + day + year;
        if(typeof(evtd[ix])!="undefined")
        {
            var html = '<h5>'+evtd[ix]["title"]+'</h5>';
            var eleft = $(this).position().left;
            var etop = $(this).position().top;
            $("#tt").html(html).css({
                left:  Math.max(eleft-($(this).width()/2),0),
                top:   Math.max(etop+$(this).height()+7,0)
            }).show();
        }
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $("#tt").hide();
    });
});

</script>
<style>
.nm{
    margin:0;
}

#tt{
    max-width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#E9EAEE;
    padding:8px;
    display:none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>

<div id="scene">MobeScene Events</div>
<div id="tt"></div>
```

Comment: try to write your function in $(document).ready()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind your event like this :

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".ui-state-default",function(e){
   //Your stuff
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on) for further explications!