# How to Replace all my live() functions to on() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, client

As Jquery 1.9  deprecated `live()` function,So I have to change those to alternative `on()`.

Everything seems fine.

In my project i am using almost >100 `live()` functions.They should work  great if I go there  each place and change to `on()`.

Is there any efficiant way or `script` to use `on()` function,where ever i am using `live()` now ??

This would save lots of my time.

Please suggest any other options too.

Thank.

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery 1.7 - Turning live() into on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/jquery-1-7-turning-live-into-on) and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15549448/1493698).

Comment: Are you wanting to make each `.live()` call continue to work by calling `.on()` in turn? Or are you wanting to do a *search and replace* so you're no longer using `.live()` at all?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah,If i do search and replace, if any other text is there named as live it will replace there also and it may cause some other troubles for me.

Comment: Regex-based search and replace shouldn't have such a problem.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah,that is a better option,but i done that 50 funtions and made a question for remaining 200 function :) well as eli suggested will try migrated script if it is light weight otherwise will do the same as you suggested.thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can tweak this a lil bit!

just extend jquery with a `.live()` function by your own which internally points to `.on()`.

```
    (function(jQuery) {
        // Store a reference to the original remove method.
        var originalOnMethod = jQuery.fn.on;

        // Define overriding method.
        jQuery.fn.live = function() {
            // event is bind for the elements added dynamically as well. 
            if(typeof arguments[0] == "string" && typeof arguments[1] == "function"){
                $(document).on(arguments[0], this.selector, arguments[1]);
            }else{//applied when proper live syntax is not followed and event will not fire for dynamically added elements  
                originalRemoveMethod.apply( this, arguments );
            }

        }
    })(jQuery);
```

I just created this function and tested, it works but you never know where it breaks. Do reply if it needs anything to coagulate. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) which is used to detect and restore APIs or features that have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9.

Comment: .. I second this.. <3..gorgeous answer ever..