# appending file inputs not working on ajaxfileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a plugin called, ajaxfileupload https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js

My problem is that when I dynamically append an input file, the plugin events are not applied to that newly appended input file.

This is how the plugin is being called on click of the file input:

```
$("#mcq_option_list input[type=file], #question_name input[type=file], #test").ajaxfileupload({
```

This is my append function:

```
$(this).before('<div class="answer_div"><input id="'+new_num+'" class="rb" type="radio" value="'+new_num+'"><label for="'+new_num+'" class="mc_label"><strong class="abcdWrapper">'+next_letter+'</strong></label><div class="fake-input"><input type="text" class="long_input" placeholder="Enter Sub Option here..." name="data[Quiz][option][]" autocomplete="off"><span></span><div class="inputWrapper"> Upload Image<input class="fileInput" type="file" name="data[Quiz][image]['+new_num+']" id="test"></div></div><a href="#" class="delete-scale-question"></a></div>');
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: So, you expect us to study your question without any code?

Comment: does you r input tag has a onclick function like <input class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();" /> else you have to use like $('input').bind('live', function(){ //user plugincode } );

Comment: jQuery events are added to elements which match the selector criteria at the time of execution. If you add new elements to the DOM later, they won't get events attached properly. jQuery's `.live()` checks elements on-the-fly to see if they match. It's slow, though so avoid it if you can - better to add the handlers/events when you add elements to the DOM

Comment: @SAM I tried your solution but it gave me Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxfileupload is not defined

Comment: Hi @Basic isn't "live" deprecated already?

Comment: @comebal Sorry, should've been [`.on()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8021436/156755) - I hadn't had my coffee but the same point applies. Are you expecting events to be added to elements which weren't in the DOM when you ran the selector?

Comment: Hi @Basic can you tell me exactly how to implement "on"?

Comment: @comebal Click the link in my previous comment (the .on() was a hyperlink) and look at the first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer already, its right that I should enclose everything in an "on" statement.

Here is the full code:

```
$("#mcq_contain").on("click", "#mcq_option_list input[type=file], #question_name input[type=file], #test", function(){
     $(this).ajaxfileupload({
          // Code goes here
     }); 
});
```