# Alternative to jquery live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using .live() in my jquery code but it some how fails when the html is generated dynamically, so is there a alternative for .live() in jquery?

Comment: Update your jQuery to a recent version and use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: `.live` is depreciated now :)

Comment: It's not deprecated, it's removed altogether. Anyway [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) tells about the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `.live` is <strike>depreciated</strike> removed, and is [replaced with `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live()

If you're generating elements "on the fly", you need to bind them to a function, and as they're not already in the DOM, you'll need to bind to the document, and delegate to the specific element:

```
$(document).on("event", "element", function(){
    //do what you need here
});
```

As you've not provided any code, I can only give you a general idea as demonstrated above

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is depreciated, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score -3):

the purpose of live is exactly to works when html is generated dynamically. Maybe you have to put your .live call inside a $(document).ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("class selector").live(function(e){
    // your code here
  })
});
```

and, like commented by others in the question, live() should be replaced by a new syntax you can see here : [Turning live() into on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to wrap `.live()` in a document ready event since its purpose is, as you said, to work regardless of when the target elements are created.

Comment: Yes it makes a lot of sense : without document.ready, `$` may not be loaded.

Comment: ... how are you using `$(document).ready()` if `$` isn't available?

Comment: That's a good question I can't answer to. I know that by experience: sometimes on really slow server, $("").live() gives an error "$ is not defined", and it never does when inside a .ready