# jQuery cannot get value of input field when using closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of the input field with class `keyHash` when I click on the link with class `loadKey`. However, all I keep getting is `undefined`?

How is this done? Shouldn't this have worked?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/2/)

```
<div class="accounts hash">
    <input type="text" class="input-tiny keyHash">
    <i class="icon-plus loadKey">Click</i>
</div>

$('.loadKey').live('click', function() {

    alert($(this).closest('.keyHash').val());

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`.closest()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/),for each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its **ancestors** in the DOM tree but here **input with class input-tiny and keyHash** is not the **ancestor** but its **sibling** then in that case try below answers.

Try using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) as shown :

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {
    alert($(this).siblings('.input-tiny.keyHash').val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/4/)

As per your html structure `.siblings()` shown above will work just fine but if you have other elements with **class input-tiny and keyHash** which are siblings of `.loadKey` then try `:last` selector :

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {
   alert( $(this).siblings('.input-tiny.keyHash:last').val() );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/10/)

**OR**

Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) as shown :

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {
    alert($(this).prev('.keyHash').val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/6/)

**OR**

Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) with `:first` selector as shown :

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {
   alert( $(this).prevAll('input:text[class="input-tiny keyHash"]:first').val() );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/11/)

**OR**

Use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) as shown :

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {
   alert( $(this).parent().children('input:text[class="input-tiny keyHash"]').val())
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/13/)

Don't use `.live()` its `deprecated since jquery version 1.7`(refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) instead use `.on()` as shown :

```
$(document).on('click','.loadKey',function() {
    alert($(this).prev('.keyHash').val());
});
```

Note :- Above shown `.on()`(**event delegation**) example is only be used when you are adding html dynamically inside DOM with jquery.

Comment: Ok! Thannks. I'll go with prev then.

Comment: @Norman..okk great and read other comments also in the answer use `.on()` instead of `.live()`

Comment: and as far as `.siblings()` is concerned it will perfectly work as per questioner question.

Comment: @TJ...you are completely mistaken my friend plz read this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery

Comment: @TJ...there is no need of event delegation in fiddle i know that..but in OP's question he is using `.live()` so its replacement in newer versions of jquery is with `.on()` and i have shown that in my answer with explanation.

Comment: @Norman..if you want other options apart from `.prev()` then i have updated the answer you can use any one of them..

Answer (score 2):

by documentation of closest, it is checks only the current element, and then its ancestors, in your case the input field is not ancestor, it is sibling

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

you can not acheive this using closest only

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method:

```js
$('.loadKey').on('click', function() {
      alert($(this).prev('.keyHash').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accounts hash">
    <input type="text" class="input-tiny keyHash">
    <i class="icon-plus loadKey">Click</i>
</div>
```

*Side note:* the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated in favour of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from jQuery 1.7

*Side note:*
 `.on()` method is used for binding all event handlers from jQuery 1.7.
The `.click()` method internally uses `.on()`, it's just an alias for `.on()`. using `.click()` is just an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c4qr6te1/1/)

```
 $('.loadKey').on('click', function () {

      alert($(this).parent().find('.keyHash').val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.loadKey').click(function() {

```
alert($(this).prev().val());
```

});

OR

$('.loadKey').click(function() {

```
alert($(this).prev('.keyHash').val());
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me
***http://jsfiddle.net/v25kt10r/9/***

```
<div class="accounts hash">
    <input type="text" class="input-tiny keyHash">
    <i class="icon-plus loadKey">Click</i>
</div>
$('.loadKey').click(function() {

    alert($('.keyHash').val());

});
```

**or**

```
$('.loadKey').click(function() {

    alert($('.input-tiny').val());

});
```

Comment: But, what if there are several such divs on the same page? Will clicking on loadkey give the value of the input just near to it?