# Cannot click on html elements inside bootstrap popover title html

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover with `html:true;` I want to click on an element in the title, to close the popover, but it does not seem to do the job.

test fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/1362/

Comment: I have seen your jsFiddle Demo - It seems there are some issue with your HTML syntax. See the update jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/9P64a/1364/

Comment: Thats not what I want. Can you tell me, what is wrong with the html syntax? It works just fine for me. Also, with jquery 1.8 and .live, this will work. But I want to move on to newer versions, and .on

Comment: @Prog There is nothing wrong with the HTML syntax.  He's passing in HTML mark-up to an element's custom attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dynamically creates and deletes the popover element ever time the element appears / disappears (as opposed to showing and hiding an element that is only created once).  To account for this, you need to list the parent container when you use jQuery's `.on()` method.

Change

```
$('#btncancel').on("click",function()
```

to

```
$('body').on('click', '#btncancel', function()
```

The above looks for the element `#btncancel` within the HTML `body` element and will do so even if `#btncancel` is created / deleted / recreated on the DOM.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/1369/)

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery you are using??

In your fiddle

```
$('#popoverData').popover({ html: true });
$('#btncancel').live("click",function(){
    $('#popoverData').popover('hide');
});
```

I used live() for generated pages and frames. But in jQuery 1.9 this function is deprecated and does not work.

Already answered here
[Turning live() into on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery)

Update

```
$('#popoverData').popover({ html: true });
$(document).on("click", '#btncancel', function () {
   $('#popoverData').popover('hide');
} );
```

Comment: I am using 1.11.1. Live is not working there. I do use .on, but that is not working either.

Comment: This one, with 1.8.3 and .live, it works. Yes. But not with a newer version and .on

Comment: Thanks, Gorostas, I saw your answer. log was not showing "heat" in console. I tried changing jquery versions, but to no avail. But thanks again. it did give me some ideas.