# jQuery: doesn't recognize mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

It really simple, but for some reason the second segment doesn't work at all.
Clicking a card doesn't do ANYTHING.

```
$('.container__card').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('container__card container__card--hover')
});

$('.container__card--hover').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('container__card--selected container__card--hover');
});
```

Comment: You need to make it a `live` type function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are adding classes dynamically so use [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click' , '.container__card--hover', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('container__card--selected container__card--hover');
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('.container__card').hover(function(){ 
   $(this).toggleClass('container__card container__card--hover')
});

$(document).on('click' , '.container__card--hover', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('container__card--selected container__card--hover');
});
```

```css
.container__card--hover{
  color:green;
  font-size:20px;
}
.container__card--selected{
  color:red;
  font-size:30px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container__card">First hover and then click me please!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.container__card').on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('container__card--hover')
});
```

check example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/142428/

Comment: This only works because you're not changing the classes on the hover event like the OP is. You need to use event delegation for this to work as the OP requires.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It does not make sense add the class on hover using jQuery. You can do it using just CSS

Answer (score 0):

Update from

```
 $('.container__card--hover').click(
        function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('container__card--selected container__card--hover');
        }
    );
```

to

```
 $(document).on('click' , '.container__card--hover', 
        function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('container__card--selected container__card--hover');
        }
    );
```

**Reason** - It is possible that the element and or class on element was not present at the time the selector ran to bind the elements. Hence, use on for dynamic elements.

For reference - [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @mplungjan It's quite obvious from the code supplied that the object is toggling classes so the event would need to be an 'on' live function.

Comment: @mplungjan - The class was not present. Hence, you will need to take care of dynamically added classes

Comment: I see. My bad..

Comment: Interestingly, if it is there and you toggle it off and on, it is still available https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kgw55b0t/

Comment: @mplungjan - Now check with .on -> https://jsfiddle.net/6yo1ecdj/ . I hope that clarifies