# How do I convert syntax .live() to .on() - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a wordpress plugin that broke with update of jquery. Would like to fix it for myself and others since the plugin has been abandoned.

It seems this line is one of the culprits:

```
$nice_navigations.find("ul a").live("click", function(e, isFromLI)
```

I've read the documentation and tried:

```
$nice_navigations.on('click', 'ul a', function(e, isFromLI))
```

But I get an error. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: `$nice_navigations.find("ul a").on("click", function(e, isFromLI)` should work

Comment: @imvain2 no it would not, that is not event delegation

Comment: @epascarello oopss I was looking as a click handler, not delegated event handler.

Comment: *"But I get an error."* That tells us zero about the problem. Is there an error message in the console? Is it not firing the event? What is the issue? What is the exact code since what you have in both cases is not valid.

Comment: Unless you just copied and pasted/typed wrong. There is an extra `)` at the end where `{` should start the function.

Comment: You're missing the body of the function.

Comment: for better understanding of convert syntax .live() to .on() - jquery please review this thread ------> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery

Answer (score -2):

Got it working with

```
$nice_navigations.on("click", "ul a", function(e, isFromLI)
```

Comment: That's the same code you said didn't work in the question...?

Comment: It's not exactly the same code. Double quotes instead of single quotes made it work properly. Thank you for responding and for everyone being so helpful. Appreciate it.

Comment: Double quotes and single quotes are treated the same way in JS. Changing them over will have absolutely no effect. I'm responding because this answer does not solve whatever problem was presented in the question.

Comment: My apologies, I believe it was the additional paren on the end that I initially had.